# Package installation uninstallation error

Tags: 13.04, apt, software-center, initramfs

For last few days, whatever software installtion/uninstallation I do with apt-get/software center it is getting ended up with message:

```
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu0.8) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-32-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fuse failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-32-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

But the installtion/uninstalltion of softwares seems to be happen successfully.

Could anyone suggest a possible fix for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove all old kernals (everything that has a revision number except what `uname -r`)

I did a mod from the others (someone may have a better way of doing this)

list everything installed and store to "to_remove.txt":

```
dpkg -l linux-* | grep ii > to_remove.txt
```

the second column is what you want (discard the rest) also make sure that you remove the entry that corresponds to `uname -r` and remove anything that DOES NOT have a revision number after it (where the revision numbers look like `linux-headers-3.2.0-74`)

then you can pass all those into dpkg:

cat to_remove.txt | xargs sudo dpkg -r

Please be careful with this and make sure you are only removing the correct ones.

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command on terminal to update `initramfs`

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: I got following output: `update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-32-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fuse failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-32-generic with 1.`

Comment: try to remove unused kernals by following the link http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/ubuntu-cleanup-how-to-remove-all-unused-linux-kernel-headers-images-and-modules/